# Jquery Validate Multiple Conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a field with multiple conditions. I've got validation working with a single condition, but I'm not sure how to go about adding in addl conditions. Here's what I have so far:

```
priceEstimate: {
          required: function() {
          return $('#jobType').val() != '8';
          }
        }
```

I also need to make sure that the value of #jobType does not equal '9' or '10' either. I tried using an or operator, and that didn't seem to do the trick.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of writing a complex function for the `required` rule, look into creating a whole new custom method with the `addMethod` method.

Answer (score 4):

```
priceEstimate: {
          required: function() {
          var jobType = $('#jobType').val();
             if (jobType < '8' && jobType > 10)
             {
                 return true;
             }else{
                 return false;
             }
          }
        }
```

There are likely simpler ways to write it... but that will do ya. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

---

In response to Jeremy's comment:

```
priceEstimate: {
    required: function ()
    {
        var jobType = Number($('#jobType').val());
        var _return = true;
        switch (true)
        {
            case (jobType <= 1):
            case (jobType >= 8 && jobType <= 10):
                  _return = false;  
                break;
        }
        return _return;
    }
}
```

Ok, what we did here is a cascading switch.  The expression is set to true, so it will run each case... we're then putting our logic in each individual case.

We know we don't want 1 or 0, so I have just have it set to false if it is equal to 1 or below, without a break in that case, it will simply run on to the next case and validate even further, so you'll want to try and keep the cases in order least -> greatest if nothing for the sake of your own sanity, lol.

Also I'm using Number() to flesh out the numeric value in the input, just in case, this way we also don't have to encapsulate all of our checks with quotes ('10') and they're treated like actual numbers and not just representations that may be translated into something that would fail the logic your striving for.

Comment: I have a jobType with a value of '0' and another with a value of '1' that don't validate using this method. All the other jobTypes (2-7) work just fine. Any idea how you would solve this?

Comment: I appreciate the update, however, this results in the same behavior as the original approach. Everything works correctly except for jobType 0 and jobType 1.

Comment: I'll test it a little further when I get home from work... busy day today :D. Only have about and hour left lol.

Comment: Just wanted to check back on this. This approach still isn't correctly validating for 0 and 1. Everything else validates correctly.